# How to create a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I cannot believe that this doesn't work. I guess I am missing something fundamental. I am trying to make a list of tuples:

```
newtags = []
print newtags
newtags = newtags.append(('{','JJ'))
print newtags
```

output is:

```
[]
None
```

I should be getting a list of tuples instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.append()` doesn't return anything. Your code will work fine if you remove the preceding `newtags =`:

```
newtags = []
print newtags
newtags.append(('{','JJ'))
print new tags
```

Which now runs as:

```
[]
[('{', 'JJ')]
```

---

Here's another example:

```
>>> arr = []
>>> print arr.append(9)
None
>>> arr
[9]
>>> arr = arr.append(8)
>>> arr
>>> print arr
None
>>>
```

Comment: Sure. I did a stupid mistake I am not sure of a should delete the question but i hope the points for you will stay.

Comment: @Brana, no they won't :)

Answer (score 1):

The method `append()` modifies the list **in-line**. So, it doesn't return anything (i.e. returns `None`):

```
newtags = []
newtags.append(('{','JJ'))
```